# LyX 2.3 Crashes

Tags: lyx

I just installed the latest version LyX 2.3.0 in Windows 10.

There is one problem. After you click Document -> View(PDF pdflatex). You can see the generated pdf file in adobe acrobat. Then you save it, and close the pdf.

After you close the pdf file, LyX 2.3.0 then crashes. It does not happen for LyX 2.2.3.

What are the problems?

Comment: Sorry but this site is not really the right place to ask about application crashes. Add a bug report to the bug tracker: https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome

Comment: I had the opposite problem (LyX 2.3.0 broke Acrobat) and I wrote here: lyx-users@lists.lyx.org.

Comment: This issue was reported here: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11210